# how to send 1kk post http requests. Whats the fastest way?

Tags: bash, http, curl, post

Im trying to learn how to send many post http requests
At the moment im using bash + curl &
it makes around 20k post requests during 24 hours.
No matter if i maximize the threading or not the total number of sent requests do not change
How to send 1kk post requests a day? Is it possible with bash + curl?
i have 1k mbps channel

Comment: 20k posts in 24 hours means 4.3 secs per request when doing it in serial. Why is it so slow?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

Read the above, and then figure out what the appropriate headers are, before the POST command.  HTTP's commands are in plain text.

Once you know that, the next question is how to get the POST command into the port of the target machines, with the least possible amount of overhead.  For that, I would probably use netcat; but it likely wouldn't be hard to write something for this in Assembly, as insane as that sounds.  We're only talking about text and port addresses, after all.

Put POST in eax, (along with strlen brain damage, which I've seen relatively easy solutions for) put port address in ebx, put the relevant kernel service number in ecx, and then call the kernel interrupt.  TCP/IP itself may not be quite as simple as that, perhaps; but plenty of other things are.

Comment: wow, this sounds very interesting. At the moment im checking curl + parallel. Running 900 threads but for some reason only up to 40 running curls are shown by the ps aux. Im looking at the 'ab', but turns out it cant output pages html content. For what you did say i bet there should be some ready solutions